# What prevents GRASS and SAGA integration into QGIS when users aren't administrators?

Tags: qgis, installation, windows, qgis-processing

Windows version of QGIS 2.0 using the stand alone installer. I have been able to tie up the functionality using the Options and Configurations settings in the Processing menu.

This works fine in a standard PC and logged in as an "administrator". However something is preventing it from working with the same QGIS setup conditions when not logged in as administrator.

Can anyone shed any light on what might be happening here - especially what process the Processing tools go through when a non-QGIS module is activated. Non-administrators cannot write to the QGIS folder, nor can they put executable files into temporary folders. Could it be one of these issues?

Comment: Can you edit your question to explain what you mean by "preventing it from working"? Does it not start, crash, not allow data to be edited, or something else.

Comment: On further inspection it seems to be something to do with the users system rather than anything to do with GRASS or SAGA - I would be very interested if anyone has ever come across a similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

If the simple user can not do things an administrator can do, it is most probably a matter of user access rights.

GRASS and SAGA create temporary files in certain folders, which might be not allowed by default to all users. You can either grant the user these rights on the folders, or change the folder of the temp files to a place where the user has full rights. Some modules allow to choose between storing temporarily or as a normal file in a selectable folder.

Comment: I've been taking a look at this - can anyone point me in the direction of a list of the folders that GRASS and SAGA create and use?

Comment: I have no such list, but apps/qgis/python/plugins and the subfolders, and apps/Python27/Lib/encodings have files recently modified. If you are suffering restrictions, better try the OSGEO4W installer. It can be installed onto another drive, without Windows system restrictions. Or choose another installation target than C:\Programs